# How can I start my app in CRA and have it open with the Edge browser?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, microsoft-edge

I have a project in [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/). I am using Windows 10 and my default browser is Firefox. I would like my project to start with the Microsoft [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge) browser and not with Firefox. I have used a line like this in the *package.json* script to open with Chrome and it works:

```
"start: react": "cross-env BROWSER = chrome react-scripts start",
```

But if I put this for Edge it doesn't work for me:

```
"start: react": "cross-env BROWSER = edge react-scripts start",
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Re *"I have a project in CRA"*: Do you mean *"I have created a project using CRA"*? (*[Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)*). (Not a rhetorical question.)

Comment: That's what I meant. I see that you have also understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:
The detail was that I placed the script line in the following way using the browser name **"edge"**:

```
"start: react": "cross-env BROWSER = edge react-scripts start",
```

But the name of the browser is **"msedge"**. In this way the script line looks like this:

```
"start: react": "cross-env BROWSER = msedge react-scripts start",
```

This way it works properly.